# Migration to Timeline: Best practice to avoid double posting?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-timeline

We currently post (or allow a user to post) on a wall when one of our visitors perform certain actions (such as purchasing a ticket, so usually max one post per day). With the new Timeline, we won't need to do this any longer as we'll be publishing actions instead via the new Graph.

As the Timeline isn't available to everyone yet, what's the best way to migrate over?

We don't want to just stop posting the wall posts now because for 99% of people they won't be visible and we'll get a dip in referral traffic, however for the people who do have timeline enabled, we don't want to be posting twice

Is there a way of detecting if a user is timeline enabled, or do people have another suggestion?